# JQ: remove nested key and keep other main array key intact

Tags: jq

I have a json file looking like this:

```
{
  "parents": [{
    // array of objects
  }],
  "modules": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
}
```

I want to remove they key `b` of the object modules.

I am running this command: `jq "with_entries(.value |= del(.b))"`

But this fails when the `parents` array is present. I get

> Cannot index array with string "b"

How can I make the command ignore the parents array and only work on the modules object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea was right, but you missed the selecting the object desired inside `with_entries()`, hence your delete operation was attempted on *all* the objects in your JSON.

Since the `parents` record is an array type and not an object , the `del` function throws out an error that its not able to index the array with the given name. You need to do

```
with_entries( select(.key == "modules").value |= del(.b) )
```

The `select()` function filters that object keyed by name `"modules"` and applies the delete action on that object alone.

<sup>[jq-play snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/X6vgw8aPd3)</sup>

Comment: Quick question from a relative jq newbie, if you don't mind: if you remove the `|= del(.b) ` operator part from your expression, you get the `Cannot use null (null) as object key` error. How can it be null and yet be available for `|=`?

Comment: @JackFleeting: Got the reason. Basically `with_entries(x)` is defined as `to_entries | map(x) | from_entries`. When you removed the delete operation and selected only the object to be inside `with_entries`, the object is fetched all right, but the object result cannot undergo transformation with `from_entries`, because the result is not in a right format for the l - https://jqplay.org/s/218qwc2EJi

Comment: Learn something new every day! Thanks.

Comment: @JackFleeting: Also my personal recommendation, is to not use `with_entries` while getting used to the tool, but use `to_entries` and `from_entries` to see how the transformation works